# Exposing event in Custom Usercontrol - Window Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-store-apps

I seem to be having a problem exposing events in Xaml. I have declared a public eventhandler in a custom user control like such.

```
public sealed partial class FoodItemControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<StringEventArgs> thumbnailClicked;

    public FoodItemControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }



    private void Thumbnail_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = thumbnailClicked;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new StringEventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

But when I go to assign an event to it in xaml the exposed eventhandler can't be found. I.e

```
<local:FoodItemControl thumbnailClicked="SOMETHING" />
```

Am I missing something in the example I found?

**EDIT**: It would seem that my problem was that I was defining the event as a EventHandler< StringEventArgs >. It worked once I changed this to simply EventHandler I.e

```
public event EventHandler thumbnailedClicked;
```

However I still do not really understand why?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a dependency property and register the property to expose it in a user control :

```
public sealed partial class FoodItemControl : UserControl
{
    public EventHandler thumbnailClicked
    {
        get { return (EventHandler)GetValue(thumbnailClickedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(thumbnailClickedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty thumbnailClickedProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("thumbnailClicked", typeof(EventHandler),
    typeof(FoodItemControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));


    public FoodItemControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `TypedEventHandler` type:

```
public event TypedEventHandler<FoodItemControl, StringEventArgs> thumbnailClicked;
```

This allows you to specify your own event arguments class that derive from `EventArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

I came here from google and it is the only issue out there related to event handlers in custom controls. For me the root cause of the issue was quite simple, but it took me a long time to find it, and you **overread it so easy.**

That is what I tried:

```cs
public EventHandler<IList<Guid>>? MyCustomEvent;
public EventHandler? MyCustomEvent2;
```

And this is what works:

```cs
public event EventHandler<IList<Guid>>? MyCustomEvent;
public event EventHandler? MyCustomEvent2;
```

I  forgot to add the `event` in front of the `EventHandler`. Note that the questionsmark `?` are used, because I've [enabled the nullable feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) in this winui3 project. Now everything works fine again, no need to add anything complicated.